# How to delete this data from firebase?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How can I delete this entry from firebase? How to delete the marked data from firebase?

[image: snapshot]

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.

```
const deleteItem = (coin) => { // coin is passed from API
  firebase
    .database()
    .ref("favorites/" + coin.id)
    .remove();
};
```

Comment: Both the question and answer is a little vague. That could be helped by telling us what `coin.id` resolves to. Is it `binancecoin` or is it `-Magtpt...`?